# Table Structure (Missing Primary Key)

Tags: sql

I'm developing an online shop application which includes a table named 'tbl_items'. The primary key for each item is the 'item_id' field.

Now, I want to add an option for each item posted on the shop to be associated with multiple pictures describing the item (unlimited amount of pictures per item), so I created another table called 'tbl_item_pictures' which includes two columns - 'item_id' and the url of the picture (varchar with the size of 2083).

I believe this structure isn't the best and it might be due to the fact it's already late where I live and I just can't think of any better solution, but I'm kind of lost. I would really not like to leave the table without a primary key, nor I want to assign a primary key to both of my fields.

Any ideas of what I can add/change in my current structure to make this work?

Comment: A side note that may avoid some headache. If you already know it's a table then you probably don't need to put `tbl_` in front of it. Depending on your DBMS _ can be a wildcard this can cause problems with searching through sys.tables later(rare I know but it can be an issue). I usually just use capitals to bookend tables. Example instead of `tbl_item_pictures` you could do `ItemPictures`

Comment: Indeed correct, that's just a method of work I'm used to since long time ago. Never encountered any problems with this way of operation though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common design pattern, and putting both columns into a PK is the normal solution.  If you **don't** do this you will potentially have multiple links from an item to the same picture.

There's nothing wrong with putting both columns into a PK for this.

**Update:**

to recap....

1 - Put your pictures into their own table, with an `ID` column and the `url`.

2 - In your linking table, use `tbl_itemID` and `pictureID`, and have them both be part of the PK for the lookup table.

Comment: Problem is that max key length is 767 bytes, I can't work with that.

Comment: @TommyNaidich See update, I didn't realize you had a url in here initially.

Comment: @TommyNaidich Don't use the URL.  If you need to do that, make a `pictures` table with a `pictureID` and `url` column, then link on that.

Comment: I do not have a table for pictures other than the one linking them to the item. That means I have no 'picture_id' field to use, if that's what you mean. Users upload their pictures directly to the server and once they are stored in the desired directory, the server retrieves the picture's path and uses it in order to update the item's data.

Comment: @TommyNaidich That's your issue.  You need to put those into an actual table.  If that's not possible, you can just go without a PK but you will have potential issues like the same picture being linked to the same item more than once.

Comment: I already thought of creating a whole new table for pictures which would store a unique ID and a URL for each picture, but I believe it would make things much more complicated than they should be. I mean, after loading the item I will also have to load the ID's of its pictures from a separated table, which would not help my case because then I will have to request more data from a third table once again. Seems kind of messy to me.

Comment: @TommyNaidich That's what it's like to make a proper normalized database design.  You have a lot of tables and it seems silly but it is robust and a recommended best practice by everyone for a reason.

Comment: Your answer seems reasonable enough, I accept. Thanks for your two cents!

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 possibilities:

1.) Have no primary key. atm you seem not to need one.

2.) If `item_id` and `url` are unique together use both as primary key

3.) add a third column (like `picture_id`) and fill it manually or automatically from a sequence

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would make the item_id the foreign key in the pictures table.  It's ok if there's not a primary key, unless you just want to add an additional autonumber column to have that distinction.

However, the say you have it is fine.  Every picture has its individual item_id it's attached to.

Think of it as a simple lookup table.